# Div 100% Min Height Problems

Tags: html, css

When a page contains a large amount of content, the footer is pushed down, and the page ends with the footer nicely. However, if the page has a small amount of content, the footer clings to the bottom of the content and floats halfway down the page leaving space underneath it.

Apologies, this has been covered numerous times and despite trying many solutions I'm still running into problems. Plus I'm a newbie. I can get the footer to rest at the bottom but it sometimes covers content/leaves a gap below it/covers content when resizing window/or the minimum height is larger than the window and it shows a scroll bar.

Please help.

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, code, del, dfn, em, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     border: 0px;
     font-weight: inherit;
     font-style: inherit;
     font-size: 100%;
     font-family: inherit;
     vertical-align: baseline;
}
:focus {
     outline: none;
}
table {
     border-collapse: separate;
     border-spacing: 0px;
}
caption, th, td {
     text-align: left;
     font-weight: normal;
}
table, td, th {
     vertical-align: middle;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
     content: "";
}
blockquote, q {
     quotes: "" "";
}
a img {
     border: none;
}

.container {
     width: 980px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     background: #fff;
     z-index: 0;
     position: relative;
     border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
     border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
     box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.hfeed {
     width: 700px;
     float: right;
     margin: 0;
}
.aside {
     width: 220px;
     float: left;
     margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
.aside ul {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
}
.footer {
     clear: both
}




body, input, textarea {
       font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
       color: #666;
}
body {
      background: #eee;
      min-width: 980px;
}

#content {
      padding: 0 0 15px 0;
      background-image: none;
      z-index: 0;
      position: relative;
}
#inner_content {
      padding: 0 15px 0 0;
      margin: 0;
}
#full_width {
     padding: 0 0 0 20px;
     width: 940px;
}
#full_width h1 {
     margin: 0 0 20px 0
}

.footer {
     width: 100%;
     padding-bottom: 0px;
     position: relative;
     background: #333 url(./_assets/img/bg-footer.png) left top repeat-x;
     border-top: 0px solid rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.1);
}
.footer-info {
     background: none;
     margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
     padding: 25px 20px 0px 20px;
     width: 940px;
     color: #aaa;
     z-index: -1;
}
.footer-info .latest, .footer-info .offers {
     margin-right: 20px
}
.footer-info .block ul li a:hover {
     color: #ccc
}
.footer-info .featured a.ad-125 {
     margin: 20px 5px 0 5px;
     display: block;
     float: left;
     width: 133px;
     height: 133px;
     overflow: hidden;
}
.footer-info .featured img {
     padding: 3px;
     background: #444;
     border: 1px solid #555;
}
.footer-info .featured img:hover {
     background: #555;
     border: 1px solid #666;
}
.footer-info .featured p {
     text-align: right;
     clear: both;
     padding: 5px 10px 0 0;
     margin: 0;
}
.footer-info .featured p a {
     font-size: 12px;
     color: #666;
     background: url(_assets/img/bg-link.jpg) left 1px no-repeat;
     padding-left: 17px;
}
.footer-info .featured p a:hover {
     background-position: left -12px;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #31cef5;
}
.footer-base {
     width: 100%;
     height: 30px;
     background: #111;
     margin: 0 auto 0px auto;
     padding: 0px;
     z-index: 1;
     position: relative;
     border-top: 1px solid #333;
}
.footer-base-inner {
     width: 940px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
.footer-base p {
     font-size: 10px;
     margin: 0 !important;
     padding: 0;
     border-right: none;
     line-height: 30px;
     text-align: center;
}
.footer-base p a {
     text-decoration: underline;
     color: #666;
}
.footer-base p a:hover {
     text-decoration: none
}
.textwidget {
     font-size: 11px;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.footer .menu {
     position: relative;
     top: 0;
}
.footer .menu li {
     float: none;
}
.footer .menu li a {
     text-shadow: none;
     font-weight: normal;
     line-height: 23px;
     color: #999;
     font-weight: inherit;
}
.footer .menu li a:hover {
     text-shadow: none
}
```

Comment: Please add the code in a fiddle. PS: Did you try `bottom :0px` ?

Comment: [maybe this will help](http://jsfiddle.net/vzfhX/) - the header and footer will be the height of it's content and the middle will grow to fit the rest of the screen.  If the content is too long then the footer will be pushed off the bottom (staying under the content)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pthomas366/KuTUK/

Please see the fiddle. Yes i've tried bottom: 0px. Problems im having:

- footer hovers over the content if the windows is resized or not
- there is still space under the footer (i dont know what it is, its not padding)

Answer (score 0):

For the footer, I use a simple solution:

Let's say we have this layout:

```
<div class="content">
    <p>All your page elements would go there</p>
</div>
<footer>
    <p>Your Footer</p>
</footer>
```

A simple and effective solution is this:

```
.content {
    min-height: 100vh; // vh is the vertical height of the browser viewport
}
```

That way, we make sure the footer will always be out of sight and at the bottom of the page, unless the content is bigger than the viewport of the browser.

**Downside:**

- It's CSS3, so the compatibility with old browsers is limited

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick to put your footer always to the bottom of the page. If the content is short, then it will be at the bottom of the screen. If the content is long, the footer will be after the content. It's kind of simple and works in every browser.

The HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   // ALL THE PAGE HTML GOES IN HERE
  <div id="push"></div>
</div><!—End Container—>
<div id="footer">// FOOTER HERE</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -330px;
    position: relative;
}
#footer {
    height: 330px;
    position: relative;
}
#push {
    height: 330px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Basically you get the `height` of your `footer` and put the same `height` to `#push`. Then you add negative `margin-bottom` to the `container` div, again the same `height`.